# Why won't this Java array's .sort method work?

Tags: java, arrays

Starting to think I'm using the wrong book for learning. I've copied this word-for-word from Sam's Learn Java, but the `.sort(names);` method is undefined for type of array.

I have a feeling it's to do with the `public static void main(String[] args) {` call, but I don't know how to amend it.

```
package arrays;

import java.util.*;

public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String names[] = { "Lauren", "Audrina", "Heidi", "Whitney",
                "Stephanie", "Spencer", "Lisa", "Brody", "Frankie", "Holly",
                "Jordan", "Brian", "Jason" };
        System.out.println("The original order:");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + ": " + names[i] + " ");
        }
        Arrays.sort(names);
        System.out.println("\nThe new order:");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + ": " + names[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't name your class `Arrays` then, or at least qualify the second `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: What [Thomas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/540873/thomas-jungblut) says (+1). Pro tip: to print your array contents, you're better off with `Arrays.toString(names)` instead of indexed iteration.

Comment: Thanks all. Didn't even occur to me :\ @Mena thanks! I'm literally right at the beginning of figuring all this out, I was just hoping to run an example code and to see it work. Unfortunately my own ignorance with Java made me innocently use an inappropriate class name.

Comment: @Mena I disagree with the "pro-tip"; using `toString` means you get whatever the `toString` implementation gives you, uncustomized, without extra data that might be needed, with the brackets, etc. `String.join` if you're on JDK 8, possibly, or a util lib, but even that doesn't give you the ability to access the index.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what you gave is an answer, I only gave a hint ;-)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Sometimes (often!) that is just as useful ;) Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: :-) I've posted it as one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*([Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540873/thomas-jungblut) pointed to the answer, but as it was a comment you can't accept it; here's a CW you can accept.)*

`Arrays` is a class in the `java.util` package, which has a `sort` method. By calling your *own* class `Arrays`, you hide the `java.util` one from your code (this is sometimes called "shadowing"), so the `Arrays.sort(names);` line is trying to use a `sort` method on **your** class (and it doesn't have one).

To fix it, you have three options:

1. Change the name of your class (`ArrayTest`, whatever), or
2. Change your call to `sort` to: `java.util.Arrays.sort(names);` (so the compiler knows you're talking about `java.util.Arrays`, rather than your class), or
3. Use `import static java.util.Arrays.sort;` to import the method `sort` rather than the class `Arrays` and invoke it with `sort(names);` (without a preceding class name).